# Sublime text environment variable cache

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sublimetext3, pythonpath

My `$PYTHONPATH` env variable is set by `./bashrc`. Somehow, sublime text has an old version with the wrong value. I can confirm that other programs see new values when `$PYTHONPATH` is updated, but somehow sublime is holding onto the old one.

Ideas?

Comment: Does quitting and restarting Sublime help? I would also try starting Sublime from a terminal where you know the variable is set as you expect and see if that helps. If it does, a restart of your computer should probably clear the problem up.

Comment: just restarted, opened sublime from GUI interface.  No $PYTHONPATH at all!  Opened from command line with `subl`.  Now it loads my env vars...

this is very frustrating.  Is there a sane way to import shell vars when ST3 is opened from GUI?

Comment: What platform and build of Sublime are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04, ST3 3176

Comment: I don't use that distribution personally, but under Linux in general a process inherits the environment of the parent that started it. In the past I've had issues where changing the `bashrc` had no effect and it was because the window manager was started with the older version. If you restarted or logged out and in again and that didn't fix it, that may not help. Possibly telling it to run the app in a terminal (if you can do that under Ubuntu) would help, though.